# django 2.1 + PostgreSQL 11 + Python 3.7 - Cannot do makemigrations

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, postgis, geodjango

I'm trying to create a geospatial database with geodjango and postgis following the recommendations of the book : Python Geospatial development, 3rd Edition of Erik Westra, in order to do it I'm trying to configure my django database and to connect it to my PostgreSQL db.

After having launched my PostgreSQL database, I've created my django project and django apps. From then I'd like to apply `makemigrations` command to my `shared` app with :

`python manage.py makemigrations shared`

But then I've go the following error :

```
File "C:\Users\[...]\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError
```

I've even tried to check migrations with `showmigrations` but it makes the same error message so I've absolutely no clue what's going on.

here's my `settings.py` file:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'shapeeditor',
        'USER': 'shapeeditor',
        'PASSWORD': '(password)',
    }
}
```

I've put (password) to hide the real one but I've checked it's the good one.
The `NAME` corresponds to the database name with a `USER` who has the same name

The `shared` app is written in `INSTALLED_APPS` so I've checked I didn't forget it.

I've looked at the many posts in StackOverflow about the error I got but it doesn't correspond to what I've facing here

Comment: Are you sure your postgres is up and running? Can you connect to it using other means, like `psql` from command line?

Comment: I do, I can connect with `psql -U postgres shapeeditor` and it seems to work, I have a command line to do queries like `shapeeditor=#`

Comment: The only thing that I can suggest is adding `HOST` and `PORT` settings.

Comment: yes I've tried it too but it didn't add more to migration problem, I've just found out I had a privilege issue with my user `shapeeditor`... Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

After writing my own question I've found where it bugged...

my `USER` shapeeditor didn't have the privileges, so it couldn't work, just switched with `postgres` and I worked, I'll have to change privileges in order to make it work